# Which HTTP response code does a Rails controller return for a given class of unhandled exception?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, controller, http-status-codes

Two-part Rails question:

#### Part 1

When a Rails controller raises an unhandled exception, an HTTP 500 (Internal Server Error) status code is typically returned in the response to the caller.

However, I've observed that certain specific types of exceptions cause a different HTTP status code to be returned. For example, an unhandled `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception (as from a `find_by!` call that failed to find a matching record) causes an HTTP 404 Not Found, rather than an HTTP 500, to be returned.

Short of actually trying it, how can I know which HTTP status code Rails controllers will return for a particular class of unhandled exception?

#### Part 2

If I want to *customize* which HTTP status code controllers return for a particular class of exception -- say, a custom derived class of `StandardError` defined in my application  -- how can that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default mapping of exception classes to HTTP response codes for Rails controllers is in `config.action_dispatch.rescue_responses`, shown here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#config-action-dispatch-rescue-responses

This default behavior can be altered or extended by assigning a value to that `config.action_dispatch.rescue_responses` hash (e.g. in `config/application.rb`). For example:

```
config.action_dispatch.rescue_responses['MyCustomError'] = :unprocessable_entity
```

Comment: If you want to go beyond this and customize the entire handling of errors you can use `config.exceptions_app` which is the Rack application called by Rails when it handles an uncaught exception.

Comment: You can also manage the status code returned for each exception per controller with: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods/rescue_from